# How to create marker cluster yii2 from mysql?

Tags: yii2, google-maps-markers, marker, markerclusterer

I want to create marker cluster google maps from myql database in yii2 framework, I couldn't use the mysql database in google maps marker cluster

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<div class="maps-index" width="1070px">
    <?php
    $map = new Map([
        'center' => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.1326, 'lng' => 5.2913]), // Center of Netherlands
        'zoom'   => 7,
    ]);

    $cities = [
        'Utrecht'    => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.0841659, 'lng' => 5.0124518]),
        'Groningen'  => new LatLng(['lat' => 53.2216845, 'lng' => 6.4947123]),
        'Amsterdam'  => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.3745291, 'lng' => 4.7585311]),
        'Amstelveen' => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.2861961, 'lng' => 4.7820703]),
        'Hilversum'  => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.2315507, 'lng' => 5.0905084]),
        'Ede'        => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.052436, 'lng' => 5.6301072]),
        'Amersfoort' => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.1589302, 'lng' => 5.3077834]),
        'Zwolle'     => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.514148, 'lng' => 5.9669147]),
        'Leiden'     => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.1517316, 'lng' => 4.4466504]),
        'Rotterdam'  => new LatLng(['lat' => 51.9279514, 'lng' => 4.4203666]),
        'The Hague'  => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.0716334, 'lng' => 4.2398287]),
        'Delft'      => new LatLng(['lat' => 51.9995297, 'lng' => 4.3286785]),
        'Eindhoven'  => new LatLng(['lat' => 51.4455368, 'lng' => 5.3814706]),
    ];

    foreach ($cities as $city => $lat_lng) {
        $marker = new Marker([
            'position'  => $lat_lng,
            'title'     => $city,
            'clickable' => true,
        ]);

        $marker->attachInfoWindow(new InfoWindow(['content' => "<strong>{$city}</strong>"]));
        $map->addOverlay($marker);
    }

    $map->center = $map->getMarkersCenterCoordinates();
    $map->zoom = $map->getMarkersFittingZoom() - 1;
    ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <?= $map->display(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```php
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

use dosamigos\google\maps\LatLng;
use dosamigos\google\maps\overlays\InfoWindow;

// edofre objects instead of dosamigos
use edofre\markerclusterer\Map;
use edofre\markerclusterer\Marker;

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\helpers\Url;

$this->title = 'Maps Clusterer';
?>
<div class="maps-index" width="1070px">
    <?php
    $map = new Map([
        'center' => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.1326, 'lng' => 5.2913]), // Center of Netherlands
        'zoom'   => 7,
    ]);

    $cities = [
        'Utrecht'    => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.0841659, 'lng' => 5.0124518]),
        'Groningen'  => new LatLng(['lat' => 53.2216845, 'lng' => 6.4947123]),
        'Amsterdam'  => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.3745291, 'lng' => 4.7585311]),
        'Amstelveen' => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.2861961, 'lng' => 4.7820703]),
        'Hilversum'  => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.2315507, 'lng' => 5.0905084]),
        'Ede'        => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.052436, 'lng' => 5.6301072]),
        'Amersfoort' => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.1589302, 'lng' => 5.3077834]),
        'Zwolle'     => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.514148, 'lng' => 5.9669147]),
        'Leiden'     => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.1517316, 'lng' => 4.4466504]),
        'Rotterdam'  => new LatLng(['lat' => 51.9279514, 'lng' => 4.4203666]),
        'The Hague'  => new LatLng(['lat' => 52.0716334, 'lng' => 4.2398287]),
        'Delft'      => new LatLng(['lat' => 51.9995297, 'lng' => 4.3286785]),
        'Eindhoven'  => new LatLng(['lat' => 51.4455368, 'lng' => 5.3814706]),
    ];

    foreach ($cities as $city => $lat_lng) {
        $marker = new Marker([
            'position'  => $lat_lng,
            'title'     => $city,
            'clickable' => true,
        ]);

        $marker->attachInfoWindow(new InfoWindow(['content' => "<strong>{$city}</strong>"]));
        $map->addOverlay($marker);
    }

    $map->center = $map->getMarkersCenterCoordinates();
    $map->zoom = $map->getMarkersFittingZoom() - 1;
    ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <?= $map->display(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem ??

Comment: I want to change the value of $cities, using the values in the database @HasiburRahaman